# Gulp error: Cannot find module jshint

Tags: bash, module, gulp, jshint, npm-install

This command was run in bash.

`npm install --save-dev gulp-jshint gulp-jscs jshint-stylish`

To use jshint I ran the following command

```
gulp style
```

An error was thrown in module.js:341
Cannot find module 'jshint/src/cli'

The problem is with jshint but why?

Answer (score 3):

gulp-jshint was installed but the jshint module is not so you must install jshint globally. Run the following:

```
npm install jshint -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right import like so:
`var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');`